# info window button click not calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I want to do button click event information window on the infowindow of google map marker. Following is my code but click event does not call the function

```
function createmarker(map, marker) {
   var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "example.com",
    data: {
     email: localStorage.getItem("email_id")
    },
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
   });

   request.success(function(response) {
    for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

     marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].curlat, response[i].curlng),
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
     });

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<input type='button' value='View' onclick='joinFunction()'>" + "<input type='button' value='Join' onclick='alert(\"infoWindow\")'>"
       });
       // infowindow.setContent( '<button onclick="viewFunction()">View</button>');
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
     })(marker, i));
    } //for loop close

   }); //http close
  }; //create marker close
  function joinFunction() {

  }
```

Comment: place the event listener outside of your functions

Answer (score 1):

You can set using:

```
 infowindow.setContent('<input type="button" value="View" onclick="joinFunction()"><input type="button" value="Join" onclick="alert(\"infoWindow\")">');
```

It will work

Comment: alert message is shown but joinFunction is not called

Comment: it calls join function. where have you put function?